# Custom elements in iteration require 'v-bind:key' directives

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, v-for

In my Nuxt app I have the following line that triggers the error mentioned in the title of this question:

```
<template v-for="(project, index) in existingProjects">
    <span :key="project.projectId"></span>
```

I tried to have the `:key` attribute on the `template` element and I also tried to use just `index` as the key, to no avail.

Any idea?

Comment: You'd have to key *all* elements inside the template. If you have more than just the `span`, those elements would also need unique keys. Consider moving those elements into a component.

Comment: May be use, looping (v-for) on a div instead of template and put keys then.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve your problem :

1. You want to iterate on a `template` : 
   You have to put a key on all elements in your template because you can not put a `key` on a `template`: `<template> cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.`

```
<template v-for="(project, index) in existingProjects">
    <span :key="project.projectId">foo</span>
    <div :key="project.projectId">bar</div>
</template>
```

2. You can iterate on something else than a `template` : You just put the `key` on the parent html tag.

```
<div v-for="(project, index) in existingProjects" :key="project.projectId">
    <span>foo</span>
    <div>bar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: The first solution results in a warning `Duplicate keys detected: 'ABC'. This may cause an update error.`  Can add a suffix like `:key="project.projectId + '-span'"` to make each key unique